# Can I call a function in SQL Server 2005 without the [dbo]?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, user-defined-functions

I have a 3rd party program that insists on rewriting certain SQL statements using `UCase(value)`. `UCase` is not supported by SQL Server 2005, so I thought I could create a User-Defined-Function that returns `UPPER(value)` and assign it an Alias of `UCase`, however it appears that I still need to use `[dbo].[Alias]`

Is it possible to call a User-Defined-Function without the `[dbo]` prefix? Or is there a way to get SQL to run `SELECT UCase('abc')` as `SELECT UPPER('abc')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, no, it is not possible to call a UDF in SQL Server without prefixing it with the owner. You can find a number of discussions on this topic here:

http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=call+sql+server+function+without+dbo+prefix

The solution, of course, is to get the 3rd party to fix the application.  Is this not an option?

Comment: The 3rd party in question is Microsoft, so I don't see it happening anytime soon. The product is Microsoft Dynamics.

Comment: Wait -- MS Dynamics constructs database calls that are incompatible with SQL Server?  Something seems amiss.  Shooting in the dark here... Is it possible the app is configured to operate against a different DBMS?  MySQL and Access both support UCASE.  Does Dynamics think it's hitting one of those?

Comment: I have not been able to find any kind of setting for that, but I won't stop looking. The entire Dynamics database is SQL Server and the part we're having trouble with is their Integration Manager app. The program runs absolutely fine unless you try to pull data from two data sources that are joined on a string field. Since most of the script is done with VB, I am guessing it was something that got overlooked.

Comment: Looking at the Dynamics documentation, *only* SQL Server is supported as the primary backend for the product, so it makes sense that this issue would only arise within Integration Manager.  It seems to be making the assumption that the data source should be accessed via the JET engine, which is typically used for Access and Text Files, and is the only MS product I'm aware of that supports UCASE.

Comment: Accepting your answer anyways since you answered my original question :)

Comment: @Rachel, I would report this to Microsoft as a bug.